# Difference between polynomial data fitting and the regression model

Tags: regression, lasso, polynomial

What is the difference between polynomial data fitting and the regression model? The traditional regression used in LASSO is also just based on polynomial fitting, albeit linear. What is meant by "pure polynomial"?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  You can always interpolate a polynomial through any (finite) set of points (trusting that the $x$ coordinates are all distinct).  Regression usually isn't looking for exact interpolation...errors are permitted.  Rather you specify a parametric form for a model and then calibrate the parameters to optimize the fit to the data ("optimize" again can mean a lot of things, though "minimizing least square differences" is a pretty standard selection).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you somewhat yes. However, what is pure polynomial simply?

Comment: A pure polynomial model is a model that is just a single polynomial. Not a piecewise polynomial, say, and no non polynomial terms.

Comment: Thanks. two final questions. you mean in piecewise polynomial we can have a linear term? Also, the traditional regression used in Lasso is also just based on polynomial fitting, albeit linear. so the difference between lasso and polynomial is that lasso use linear function?

Comment: Linear polynomials are still polynomials.  I am more familiar with ridge regression than with lasso methods, but the ideas are similar.  You optimize the fit as I said, BUT you penalize a model for using unrealistic coefficients.  This can be done in a number of ways, most simply by introducing a cost term for using big coefficients.  The idea is to avoid over fitting.  Ridge methods reduce the coefficient size, Lasso actually can exclude terms if it finds them too costly to use.

Comment: The sort of thing to keep in mind:  Take some collinear points.  Easy to fit, of course.  Now modify each point by some small Gaussian noise.  Of course, the best model here is the line you started with, but say you didn't know that.  If you let the machine fit to a high degree polynomial, it certainly will try.  And it will use every term in that polynomial to try to interpolate exactly.  If the degree is high enough, it *will* fit exactly.  But that is over fitting.  The "model" you get that way will be terrible.

Comment: One difficulty with responding to this question is that it incorrectly characterizes the Lasso. Another is that the term "regression model" is vague and broad.  Some clarification of both of these would help make it answerable.